# JS issue on IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have written some code and run it on several browsers. The code worked on all the browsers except IE11. I am providing the HTML code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  handleDynamicHeight();

  window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
    handleDynamicHeight();
  });

  window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    const offsetTop = -$("#StickyInnerContainer").offset();
    console.log(offsetTop);
    $(".HorizontalTranslateContainer").css({
      'transform': 'translateX(' + offsetTop + 'px)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translateX(' + offsetTop + 'px)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(' + offsetTop + 'px)',
      '-moz-transform': 'translateX(' + offsetTop + 'px)',
    })
  });
});

function handleDynamicHeight() {
  const objectWidth = $(".HorizontalTranslateContainer")[0].scrollWidth;
  const dynamicHeight = calcDynamicHeight(objectWidth);
  $(".TallOuterContainer").css({
    'height': dynamicHeight + 'px'
  })
}

function calcDynamicHeight(objectWidth) {
  const vw = window.innerWidth;
  const vh = window.innerHeight;
  return objectWidth - vw + vh + 150;
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.StickyInnerContainer {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.HorizontalSection {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.BumperSection {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 128px 16px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.CardsContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.SampleCard {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #111f30;
  margin-right: 75px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.TallOuterContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.HorizontalTranslateContainer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  /* will-change: transform; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="BumperSection">
    <h2>Scroll down to reach the horizontal scroll section</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="HorizontalSection">
    <div class="TallOuterContainer">
      <div id="StickyInnerContainer">
        <div id="abc" class="HorizontalTranslateContainer">
          <ul class="CardsContainer">
            <li class="SampleCard"></li>
            <li class="SampleCard"></li>
            <li class="SampleCard"></li>
            <li class="SampleCard"></li>
            <li class="SampleCard"></li>
            <li class="SampleCard"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="BumperSection">
    <h2>You have left the horizontal horizontal scroll section</h2>
  </div>


  <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Every browsers are working good but IE11 is not working well. I found out that 'offsetTop' is not working in IE11. It is returning 0 everytime.

How to solve this problem?
Please help me..

Thank you..

Comment: `.offset()` returns an object with the properties `left` and `top`, not a number. https://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: I try this on Chrome and it logs `NaN`.

Comment: Did you mean to write `.offset().top`? But then shouldn't you use that in `transformY`?

Comment: I don't know why offset () is not working on my code. It says $('classname')[0].offset() is not a function. So instead I used offsetTop property. But it is also not working only in IE11.

Comment: `offset()` is a jQuery method, not a DOM method. `$('classname')` is a jQuery object, when you use `[0]` you get the corresponding DOM element.

Comment: You can use `$('selector')[0].offsetTop` to get the similar DOM attribute.

Comment: Yes I did the same thing. You will notice it on my JS code inside 'scroll' event. It works on every browser except IE11. That is the problem indeed. How can I solve this problem for IE11, sir?

Comment: I test your code and it logs `NaN` in both IE and Chrome. In you code above, it shows using `offset()` instead of `offsetTop`. Do you want to get the top coordinates of `#StickyInnerContainer` using [`offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)? If so, you can use `const offsetTop = -$("#StickyInnerContainer").offset().top;`.